# Is there any way to have Controller, ViewModel and View without Model? It's for an Index only view

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

What I want to do is a parametrized report, i would love to use SSRS or other fancy tools for this but it's sort of dangerous at this point because i don't really want to mess around with the company server and I dont have much time; Also If it's a tool it should be a free and light tool and i didn't find one by now.

So, my idea is making a simple controller with Index that will return a List  to View according to parameters and the View will use that ViewModel as Model then the users can export that list to CSV or PDF, the problem  is: MVC is asking for a real db model to complete the scaffolding, how can this be done then?

**Controller** (I call an stored proc here)

```
public class ReporteEntregasPresentacionController : Controller
{
    private EntregaMedicamentosEntities db = new EntregaMedicamentosEntities();

    public ActionResult Index(DateTime DateFrom, DateTime DateTo)
    {
        ReporteEntregasPresentacionViewModel rep = new ReporteEntregasPresentacionViewModel();

        string sqlQuery = "[dbo].[spEntregasPorPresentacion] ({0},{1})";
        Object[] parameters = { DateFrom, DateTo };            
        rep.LstEntregasPresentacionViewModel = db.Database.SqlQuery<ItemEntregasPresentacionViewModel>(sqlQuery, parameters).ToList();

        return View(rep);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**:

```
public class ReporteEntregasPresentacionViewModel
{
    public int index;
    public List<ItemEntregasPresentacionViewModel> LstEntregasPresentacionViewModel;
}

public class ItemEntregasPresentacionViewModel    {

    public string idProducto { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string EntregasTotales { get; set; }
}
```

I don't have a **View** now but i should be something like this:

```
@model EntregaMedicamentos.Models.ReporteEntregasPresentacionViewModel
<link href="~/Content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ReporteEntregasPresentacion";
}

<h2>ReporteEntregasPresentacion</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Entrega", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="card text-white bg-secondary">
        <h5 class="card-header">Search</h5>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        @Html.TextBox("DateFrom", ViewBag.currentFilter1 as DateTime?, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Desde fecha", @readonly = "true", type = "datetime" })
                        @Html.TextBox("DateTo", ViewBag.currentFilter2 as DateTime?, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Hasta fecha", @readonly = "true", type = "datetime" })
                        <button id="Submit4" type="submit" style='font-size:22px ;color:blue'><i class='fas fa-search'></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<br>
<table class="table table-striped ">
    <tr class="table-primary">
        <th>
            Código
        </th>
        <th>
            Producto
        </th>
        <th>
            Entregas Totales
        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.idProducto)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)
            </td>

            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Valor)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Then just create the model, map the desired properties over and return that to the view

Comment: mmm good point, so i can simply add a table and real model and never really using it, i'll try that.

Comment: You can use ReporteEntregasPresentacionViewModel as the Model. The example you have there should work. Is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a real table/model and then it worked fine with the viewmodel. Thanks.